# MsWord.BackgroundPrintingStatus

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I have an instance of a word document running (opened through a New Word.Application). I have populated the document and sent it to print, however, if i then use the Msword.application.quit method as the next statement it cancels the print job

I have put in a do while `MsWord.BackgroundPrintingStatus = 1` loop in but this then goes into an infinite loop.

stepping into the code and giving the print job time to run before continuing to the quit command works fine and the `MsWord.BackgroundPrintingStatus` does return to 0.

Why would a do while loop go into an infinite loop while waiting for the status to change?

Comment: OK found a way to do it.

put the quit in a do while printingstatus = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found a way to do it. put the quit in a do while printingstatus = 0